# How to disable future dates in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have used following code for this but it is not working. please help me to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            endDate: "today",

        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });


        $('.datepicker').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9^-]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try this `$("ID").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date());`

Comment: on Date change: once you get the date which is selected just parse that date in this line `$("ID").datepicker({  maxDate: selected Date() });` add this line in `on('ChangeDate')`event.

Comment: or if you want to disable dates before change than above KiRa provide the solution already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this: Datepicker has an option `maxDate`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            endDate: "today",
            maxDate: today
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });


        $('.datepicker').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9^-]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Select Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: $ is not defined...Please add jQuery link above to complete example.

Comment: Please, reconfirm my last update. Now is finally working. :)

Comment: Thanks  @abbasali.. :)

Comment: I am using Bootstrap datepicker so it is not working properly

Comment: @PraddyumnaSangvikar what problem are you facing now?

Answer (score 3):

using `maxDate:'0'` you can acchive this.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/Fa8Xx/4495/)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ',
  maxDate:'0'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to future date disable from today use `today.getFullYear() - 10` in order to disable 10 years before which means disable from 2008.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear()-10; // change according to year 0 for current
var today1 = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
$("#birthday").datepicker({
     endDate:today1,
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: if you want to future date disable from today use today.getFullYear(); because -10 show  disable 10 year before which means disable from 2008;

Comment: In the future please add additional information directly in your answer by clicking the `edit` button below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            endDate: "today",
            maxDate: today
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });


        $('.datepicker').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9^-]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Select Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include context to your source code in order to receive the proper responses. 
Please check the documentation [on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @CarlosCavero You know this is an answer and not a question, right?

Comment: Either way, take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks @Zoe I got confused maybe editing another question :(. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

Simply can do by this :It will disable from today date.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: "-1d",
        minDate: "-100Y",
        yearRange: "-100:-0"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bootstrap-4` `date-picker` you can add this attributes in input tag `"data-date-end-date" => "0d"`i

Answer (score 0):

```
var DateIssue = $("#BodyContentPlaceHolder_dat_xxxx_xxxx_True");
              var DateOpts = {
              showButtonPanel: true,
              timepicker:false,
              dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
              buttonText: "" ,
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              yearRange: "-100:+50",
              beforeShow: beforeShowDatePicker
};
    DateOpts = {
    maxDate: new Date(),
    showButtonPanel: true,
    timepicker:false,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    buttonText: "",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+50",
    beforeShow: beforeShowDatePicker
};
  $(DateIssue).datetimepicker('destroy');
  $(DateIssue).datepicker(DateOpts)
```