# how to disable all future dates in input type=DatePicker using scripting

Tags: javascript

I'm developing application in iWorkflow platform. It is an object oriented platform. I have DatePicker control for Field named Select Date :. 
I want to disable the future dates using javascript for `type=DatePicker`. But my codes isn't working.

I tried this by adding maxDate:0. But I think `$("#ctrl_DatePicker_e0leq").DatePicker` works for Input type=Text not DatePicker.

```
$("#ctrl_DatePicker_e0leq").DatePicker({
    maxDate: 0
});
```

I'm expecting correct script to disable dates greater than the current date.

Comment: you are doing it right but in case try `maxDate: '0D'`

Comment: @shenny you need should use *minDate : new Date()* , this will disable all the past dates or previous date of current date. so please do not use maxDate rather than use  *minDate : new Date()*

Comment: are you using jquery datepicker ?

Comment: first define var today = new Date() then , maxDate = today.

Comment: @shenny even i added the snippet with the same, so you can use that as well. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            endDate: "today",
            maxDate: today
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });


        $('.datepicker').keyup(function () {
            if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9^-]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
```

And:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Select Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

For more Details you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128851/how-to-disable-future-dates-in-datepicker/42128891):

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
  });
});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Date :
  <div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @ankitKanojia, But in this case the input type is datepicker not text.

Comment: @shenny okay then let me create another snippet without input type text for date picker so that you can get an idea more on that.

Comment: @shenny please see my snippet, I just updated it as per you're a requirement. added division rather than input type text.